# Gráfico highchart que importe os valores de tabela do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, select, highcharts

Tenho um sistema onde alunos são cadastrados em turmas de formações, todo aluno cadastrado está "previsto" para comparecer e quando ele comparece, além de previsto ele "realizou".

O que eu quero é fazer um gráfico usando Highcharts que compare a quantidade de alunos de determinada área que estavam previstos pra fazer aquela formação naquele mês e a quantidade que realmente realizou.

**O php:**

```
 <?php

    require('conn.php');

    $prevJan= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participantes WHERE PREVISTO = 'Previsto' and FORMACAO = 'Revues Techniques' and MES = 'jan' and AREA = 'R&D'";
    $realJan= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participantes WHERE REALIZADO = 'Realizado' and FORMACAO = 'Revues Techniques' and MES = 'jan' and AREA = 'R&D'";

    $rsp = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli->query($prevJan));
    $rsr = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli->query($realJan));

    $totalp = mysql_num_rows($rsp);
    $totalr = mysql_num_rows($rsr);

    $listap = array($prevJan);

    ?>
```

**O gráfico Highchart:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Reveus Techniques'LOP
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'R&D'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: '',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} ',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 120,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Realizado',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [<?php echo join($datar, ',') ?>],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Previsto',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [<?php echo join($datap, ',') ?>],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }
    }]
});
        </script>
```

Imagino que pra isso eu vá precisar transformar esse `select` em um valor, inserir ele em uma lista e entregar essa lista ao highchart, mas não domino essa linguagem e tenho muita ideia de como fazer isso. 
Se alguém puder me ajudar, seria ótimo. :)

*obs: Além disso, o gráfico simplesmente desapareceu da minha página*

**Imagem da tabela:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, essa estrutura da sua tabela, com dois campos pra identificar a presença pode ser convertida em um unico campo booleano.

Estrutura tabela:

```
ID | PARTICIPANTE | PRESENCA | DATA
```

> PRESENCA -> Deve ser 1 para realizado e 0 (default) para previsto.

Insira as dependencias:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Conecte com o banco de dados, e faça uma unica consulta:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM participantes';
$rs = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli->query($sql));
```

Depois disso, abra a consulta armazenada em `$rs` e construa uma array:

```
$data = [];
//$loop pela resposta no banco para construir uma array
foreach ($rs as $row) {
    $status = $row['2'];
    $date = $row['3'];
    if ($status == 0) {
        if (!array_key_exists($date, $data)) {
            $data[$date] = [];
            $data[$date]['previsto'] = 1;
        } else {
            $data[$date]['previsto'] += 1;
        }
    } else {
        if (!array_key_exists($date, $data)) {
            $data[$date] = [];
            $data[$date]['realizado'] = 1;
        } else {
            $data[$date]['realizado'] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Essa construção irá te devolver algo como isso (Esses são os dados que coloquei minha tabela para testar):

```
Array ( [2017-01-01] => Array ( [previsto] => 1 [realizado] => 3 ) [2017-02-01] => Array ( [realizado] => 3 [previsto] => 1 ) [2017-03-01] => Array ( [previsto] => 3 [realizado] => 1 ) [2017-04-01] => Array ( [realizado] => 4 ) )
```

Obs: Examine a estrutura dessa array que vais entender o que foi feito.

Agora, vamos a parte do gráfico, pra simplificar, eu fiz no modo chamado 'GAMBIARRA'.

Verifique a estrutura que o plugin pede para o resultado que você quer, no caso, peguei um gráfico em colunas.

```
//Contando registros para saber onde colocar as virgulas
$count = count($data);
$arg = '';
$arg .= 'series: [';
$a = 1;
$arg .= '{';
$arg .= 'name: "Previsto",';
$arg .= 'data: [';
foreach ($data as $key => $serie) {
    $previsto = $serie['previsto'];
    if ($previsto == '') {
        $previsto = 0;
    }
    if ($a < $count) {
        $arg .= '' . $previsto . ',';
    } else {
        $arg .= '' . $previsto . '';
    }
    $a += 1;
}
$arg .= ']},{';
$arg .= 'name: "Realizado",';
$arg .= 'data: [';
$c = 1;
foreach ($data as $key => $serie) {
    $realizado = $serie['realizado'];
    if ($realizado == '') {
        $realizado = 0;
    }
    if ($c < $count) {
        $arg .= '' . $realizado . ',';
    } else {
        $arg .= '' . $realizado . '';
    }
    $c += 1;
}
$arg .= ']}]';
?>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Comparativo de presença'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
<?php
$b = 1;
foreach ($data as $key => $serie) {
    if ($b < $count) {
        echo '"' . $key . '",';
    } else {
        echo '"' . $key . '"';
    }
    $b += 1;
}
?>
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Valores'
                }
            },
<?php
echo $arg;
?>
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

O gráfico não tem segredo, o mais complicado mesmo e trazer os dados e colocar na forma correta, se você copiar esses códigos em ordem e colocar em algum lugar, você vai ter um gráfico como esse:

[image: Gráfico]

Não aconselho você gerar os gráficos deste modo, é melhor usar das construções que o plugin fornece e indica [AQUI](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database), seu erro está na lógica da tabela, não na geração do gráfico em si, tome apenas como base.

E pra finalizar, se for utilizar muitos gráficos que irão interagir com PHP recomendo mudar para a biblioteca FusionCharts, eu acho q integração deles melhor e mais simples de ser usada, e gosto mais da documentação deles também.

Comment: Primeiro: Você lembrou de mim! Segundo: Então, a minha tabela é um pouquinho diferente, o eixo X do gráfico não recebe a data, só precisa receber o mês, que já está na tabela. Além disso, preciso que esse gráfico só seja gerado pra colaboradores que tenham realizado determinada formação de determinada área em uma tabela com participações em várias formações em várias áreas em vários meses, por isso preciso do WHERE no $sql.

Comment: Meu previsto é uma string porque pensei que poderia usar um WHERE em um select count(*). Vou colocar uma imagem da minha tabela.

Comment: Até porque na hora que o colaborador se cadastra, ele é um previsto. Quando ele comparece a formação e assina a lista de presença, depois o responsavel pela formação que vai entrar no sistema e colocar que ele realizou. Eu criei duas colunas, uma pra previsto e outra pra realizado porque eu preciso dessas duas informações, não posso perder um previsto quando um colaborador realizar uma formação.

Comment: Ah, e muito obrigada mesmo pela ajuda. :)

Comment: Você pode usar o count(*) sim, mas  nesse caso você teria de fazer duas consultas, em PHP se der pra fazer em uma query só a consulta, faz em uma e trata os dados.
Estar em data (Y-m-d) ou só o mês não vai fazer diferença, pois é uma identificação pro eixo X, você vai substituir onde meu campo tem 'DATA' pelo seu 'MES'.
E você pode colocar a clause WHERE na query com os parametros da FORMACAO e AREA sem nenhum problema que vai funcionar do mesmo jeito.
E sobre o PREVISTO e REALIZADO, todos os cadastrados são PREVISTOS, é isso ? se for, crie regras em vez de informação redundante no banco

Comment: Todo mundo é previsto e quando alguém realiza, vira previsto e realizado

Comment: O que eu tinha pensado: Fazer a consulta do previsto mês de janeiro, transformar em um valor e inserir na lista e fazer o mesmo com a consulta realizado janeiro, depois fazer a consulta do mês de fevereiro, transformar em um valor e inserir na lista, depois o mesmo pros outros meses.

Comment: Nesse ponto ali 'vira previsto e realizado' informado como informação diferente em colunas acaba complicando seu tratamento, é melhor criar a regra pra isso, faz como eu demonstrei no exemplo, abre o loop por data(mes), agrupa as informações e soma na array, depois de construida monta as series e printa o gráfico. Ta dando pra entender o que eu estou dizendo ?  Eu não estou conseguindo pensar em um jeito de fazer isso com essas duas colunas sem ter de fazer mais de uma consulta na mesma tabela, o que é errado, uma tabela = uma unica consulta.

Comment: Ta, eu copiei seu código mudando a consulta e as variáveis $data pra $MES mas não funcionou. O que era suposto que eu fizesse?

Comment: Tem certeza que mais de uma busca é uma prática tão ruim assim? Parece  um jeito que faz sentido pra mim, mesmo que não seja "otimizado"